# MVC / jQuery FireFox and window.location not working

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have this block of code and in FireFox it doesnt seem to work

```
 SignIn: function () {

    $("#message-box").hide();

    var RememberMe = false;

    if ($('#RememberMe').is(':checked') == true) {
        RememberMe = true;

    }



    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/AuthenticateUser",
        data: { UserEmail: $("#Login-UserEmail").val(), UserPassword: $("#Login-UserPassword").val(), RememberMe: RememberMe },
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {



            if (data != "") {
                $("#message-box").html(data);
                $("#message-box").slideDown();
            } else {

                  // alert("test") this dont fire either even though data ==""
            window.location.href = "/Dashboard/";
                  //tried window.location = "/Dashboard/"; not work either



            }

        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });

},
```

Comment: nothing happens and no errors

Comment: For what purpose this code is used.? when is this executed?..

Comment: The function name is Sigin. It is called when the user clicks the "SignIn" button. Once the user has been authenticated it should redirect them to the "Dashboard"

Comment: could u give a demo or something? atleast please html and other needed js.

Comment: Are you familiar with jquery and the code listing I provided? Have you ever done similar coding in javascript as the listed coding above?

Comment: No one will waste time for what you have posted here. We need something that we cud work around if u want solution. Its not my problem, its yours.

Comment: This function is being called. it is the one line of code "window.location..." that is not working... I am not sure how the demo or html can help you ..  the problem has been isolated to FF and with window.location.  the function works in IE.

Comment: check what is returning from ajax call. U said data is null rite? window.location.href will work fine in ff. I jus tried that.

Comment: data is either "" or != "" when it is "" then it should redirect using window.location...

Comment: sorry dude..i cant provide any solution without having any demo or something..hope u get a solution soon. ping me if u gets..

Comment: I found the problem.  In my ajax call I needed to specify a dataType of the return data.  I ended up specifing dataType:"text"

Comment: gr8. gud u found out urself.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have this block of code and in FireFox it doesnt seem to work

```
 SignIn: function () {

    $("#message-box").hide();

    var RememberMe = false;

    if ($('#RememberMe').is(':checked') == true) {
        RememberMe = true;

    }



    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/AuthenticateUser",
        data: { UserEmail: $("#Login-UserEmail").val(), UserPassword: $("#Login-UserPassword").val(), RememberMe: RememberMe },
        type: "POST",
        dataType:"text",
        success: function (data) {



            if (data != "") {
                $("#message-box").html(data);
                $("#message-box").slideDown();
            } else {

                  // alert("test") this dont fire either even though data ==""
            window.location.href = "/Dashboard/";
                  //tried window.location = "/Dashboard/"; not work either



            }

        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });

},
```

I needed to specify dataType:"text" for it to work in FF.  In FF it returns [object object] when the data is =""  so when I did my check if (data!="")  it is always true when in FF.